# Sampling from Sine Kernel and Airy Kernel

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis

A [determinantal process](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/determinantal-processes/) on the line is a random collection of points on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the probability of  $x_1, \dots, x_n$ lying on the random set is $\det (K(x_i, x_j))_{(i,j)}$.  Examples of determinantal processes include the eigenvalues of random Hermitean matrices with Gaussian entries and non-intersecting random walks.  I'm interested in sampling random points on the line according to the sine kernel $k(x,y) = \frac{\sin(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}$ or the [Airy Kernel](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/talks/oldtalks/Dartmouth2005.pdf) (see p 6 of the slides) which are related to the [Gaussian Unitary Ensemble](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0412017).

I thought there are algorithms for sampling from general [discrete](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3740) and continuous determinantal processes.  Maybe it's be better to sample a processes directly using [Coupling from the Past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_from_the_past) and other procedures.

Mainly,

- how does one sample points on the real line with respect to the sine kernel?
- is there a general way of sampling determinantal processes based or arbitrary kernel?

It is known these types of processes demonstrate repulsion (compared to the Poisson process) and I would like to demonstrate this in the classroom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone is still interested. The algorithm of Hough, Krishnapur, Peres and Virag was implemented here

http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0071

in the case of eigenvalues of random matrices.  The methodology uses Chebyshev approximations to do inverse sampling of the marginal distributions. The code is available here in the *Julia* RMT package:

https://github.com/jiahao/RandomMatrices.jl

Answer (score 3):

For a general algorithm for simulating points from a determinantal process, see Algorithm 18 in the paper "Determinantal Processes and Independence" by Hough, Krishnapur, Peres and Virag:

[arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503110)

This algorithm was actually implemented by some physicists at Princeton (I believe) but I am not sure if their code is publicly available.

For the sine kernel, depending on how many points you want to sample, Matlab is pretty good at computing eigenvalues of a large GUE matrix in a decently short amount of time. That would require much less work than implementing the algorithm above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm less enthusiastic than the previous answers concerning how your question is easily solvable: What tells the HKPV algorithm mentioned above is that you can exactly sample a determinantal point process (DPP) provided your kernel is a projection kernel of finite rank, or when it is a contraction with explicit eigenvalues/eigenvectors. The problem is that the sine kernel does not satisfy any of these hypothesis (neither Airy).

More precisely, the sine kernel $K_{\sin}(x,y)$ is a projection kernel but not of finite rank; the associated DPP generates  infinite configurations a.s. For sampling you may fix a compact window $A$ and then consider the restriction of the operator $K_{\sin}$ restricted to $L^2(A)$. It is not a projection, but a contraction. If you can find an explicit eigenvalue/eigenvector decomposition for $K_{\sin}$ on $L^2(A)$, then you can sample the DPP with HKPV algorithm, although you may have to stop playing the Bernoulli's after a finite number of steps. Same situation for $K_{\mathrm{Airy}}$.